# Python/Pandas bring value based on another DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe, below

```
    Key_words   Possiblities
0   ar            NaN
1   va            NaN
2   eb            NaN
3   ne            NaN
4   ke            NaN

    id  first_name  last_name   email
0   7840    Avery   Beldon  abeldon0@cyberchimps.com
1   7840    Emilie  Anton   eanton1@hp.com
2   7840    Corine  Gabey   cgabey2@state.tx.us
3   7840    Noak    Lowdyane    nlowdyane3@dot.gov
4   9907    Yetta   Kornilov    ykornilov4@smugmug.com
```

I am trying to fill **df["Possibilites"]** with df2["first_name"] if key_words in df2["first_name"] with this code:

```
for i in range(0,len(df["Key_words"])):
    df["Possiblities"].loc[i]=list(df2["first_name"][df2["first_name"].str.contains(df["Key_words"].loc[i])])
```

it returns what i expect but gives a warning also:

" SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

What should I do instead using "for loop"? more practical or right way...

Comment: [Is possible convert pic data to text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with generator with join for match multiple matched values, if necessary convert values to lowercase:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(y for y in df2["first_name"] if x.lower() in y.lower())
df["Possiblities"] = df["Key_words"].apply(f)
print (df)
  Key_words Possiblities
0        ar             
1        va             
2        eb             
3        ne       Corine
4        ke
```

Comment: so, is it decent to do with loop ? with ur way ofc..

Comment: @bibakcamki - what is size of Both DataFrame?

Comment: @jezreal for now it is 1K row. BTW ur code returns only one possbility but there are more than one

Comment: @bibakcamki - can you add expected ouput from sample data? For me match only `Corine` for data in question,.

Comment: last edit returns what i expected "ar-->Darleen,Clarance,Carree,Caroljean" but I need2 practice with ur solution, cuz my brain goes all the way with loop :))